# Entity Framework & Linq Orderby

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

We have a 3 table relationship in an MVC application that is using the EF6. For example a Customer Table related to an Orders Table(the many side) and the Orders Table is related to an OrderItems Table (the many side).

We would like in **ONE TRIP** to the database get all the records for all tables **and** be able to order each table.

We know we can use the include extension like context.Customers.Include("Orders.OrderItems") to eagerly load all data. But we keep getting errors when we try to order each table.
For example we would like to order the Customer Table by CustomerId column, and the Orders Table by Date column and the OrderItems by ProductId column.

Any assistance would be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *navigation properties* from `OrderItem` to `Order` and from `Order` to `Customer`, then you can get ordered `OrderItems' you can achieve this like:

```
var orderItems = context.OrderItems
    // Filter if needed with .When
    .Include(m => m.Order.Customer)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Order.Customer.CustomerId)
    .ThenBy(m => m.Order.Date)
    .ThenBy(m => m.ProducetId)
    .ToList();
```

But, if you want to get customers, what you can do is load ordered customers like:

```
var customers = context.Custoemr
    .Include(m => m.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderItem))
    .OrderBy(m => m.CustomerId)
    .ToList();
```

Then order `Order` and `OrderItem`. As you have loaded all data, ordering collections will not make any database call, and it will remain *one-trip to database*:

```
foreach(Customer customer in customers)
{
    customer.Orders = customer.Orders.OrderBy(m => m.Date);
    foreach (Order order in customer.Orders)
    {
        order.OrderItems = order.OrderItems.OrderBy(m => m.ProducetId);
    }
}
```